# CicuiTikZ Special Sources not recognised

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

In the package CicuiTikZ there are some special sources listed in the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf), in section 4.2.9. For some reason I can't get them to work. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,decorations,shapes.geometric}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{circuitikz}[european]
            \draw
              (0,0) to [ioosource, l_ = $I$] (0,3)
        \end{circuitikz}
     \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which should be correct according to the documentation. I'm using Overleaf to compile in PdfLaTeX so the packages should all be up to date.

Comment: Please note that your last point is not always true!

Comment: As Raaja mentions, overleaf is usually not using the very latest packages. They perfer stability. So you should figure out which version is provided by overleaf, and then use that. Or figure out which new files are needed for circuitikz, and then upload those packages to your overleaf project.

Comment: and you get my +1

Comment: So what I can see is that the special sources are added in CicuiTikZ  2016, and Overleaf is running Tex Live 2016.  I will check with my stand alone LaTeX build to see if this is really the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking into this in detail while Overleaf indeed uses TeX Live 2016 and the build in which Special Sources for CicuiTikZ is also 2016. The actual build of CicuiTikZ included in the 2016 TeX Live build is from 2015 -- and that is the reason.

Thanks to daleif and Raaja!